# Cannot run on device after installing 'cordova-plugin-mfp-push'

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am having an issue running my app on the device after installing the "cordova-plugin-mfp-push".

In Xcode , I see the error..

**Unable to install "my app"**

**the certificate used to sign "myapp" has either expired or has been revoked. An updated certificate is required to sign and install the application.**

When I remove the plugin the error goes away and I can deploy to my phone.

Can you give some hints on how to debug this issue. My certs is valid and push is enable for the certs.

I am using MobileFirst version 8 , xCode 7.3 with the mfp template

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To help propagate the changes that are added by the push framework removing the ios environment and adding it back in has resolved a similar issue in my environment:

`$ cordova remove ios
$ cordova add ios@latest`

Once you have re added the ios platform run `cordova prepare` and `cordova build ios`

Once the above steps are completed you can open the project in Xcode.  Here Xcode will find two warnings that can be automatically handled by Xcode that are worth updating.  Review what will be updated and correct the warnings. See image below:

[image: xcode auto fix]

At this point you should be able to run the project successfully.

Answer (score 0):

dUsing APNS requires the Push Notification capability and therefore a new certificate. You can renew the certificate within the Apple Developer Portal (Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles). 
Alternatively you could use Xcode 8 which simplifies certificate handling a lot when using automatic code signing.

Comment: Can you try Xcode 8 to let it automatically fix other issues?

Comment: Thanks but is a requirement  for "cordova-plugin-mfp-push" to have Xcode 8..  I would rather not upgrade yet ...

Comment: You can use Xcode 7 and 8 in parallel so you do not "loose" the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After adding mfp-push plugin I was unable to install the app on iPhone with error saying "The application does not have valid signature". 
I could resolve this by removing cordoba-plugin-mfp-push & also cordova-plugin-mfp, then adding only cordova-plugin-mfp-push, which in turn adds cordova-plugin-mfp.

Comment: There was mismatch in versions of mfp & mfp-push plugin